# Colorbar gets overlapped with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray, colorbar

After setting the right spacing between the subplots the `colorbar` gets overlapped with the plots, even though I have used `pad` keyword in `cbar_kwargs`.

```
months = [
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
    'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December',
]
ds_anomalies = ds_mm - ds.ILD_T05.mean(dim='TIME')

pl = ds_anomalies.ILD_T05.plot.contourf(
    levels=20,
    col='month',
    vmax=40,
    vmin=-40,
    col_wrap=3,
    cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
    cbar_kwargs={
        "label": "MLD in m ", "shrink": 0.8, "aspect": 30, "pad": 0.8
    },
    subplot_kws={"projection": ccrs.PlateCarree()},
)

for i in pl.axes.flat:
    i.coastlines()
    plt.subplots_adjust(
        left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3
    )
    i.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
    i.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)

for i, ax in enumerate(pl.axes.flat): #to give names to the monthly plots 
    current_title = ax.get_title()
    assert current_title[:len('month = ')] == 'month = '
    month_ind = int(current_title[len('month = '):]) - 1
    ax.set_title(months[month_ind])
plt.savefig("fig.pdf")
```

[image: plots]

Comment: If you use `plt.tight_layout()` instead of calling subplots_adjust directly, does that help?

Comment: No. It's still overlapping with some parts of the plots. Though I was able to position the colorbar by using right values of ``fraction`` and ``anchor`` keywords in the ``cbar_kwargs``.

Comment: nice! glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

I tried with some keywords available for the `cbar_kwargs` such as `fraction` and `anchor` and it seems to work. Had to adjust the values little bit.

here's the code

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
ds_anomalies=ds_mm- ds.ILD_T05.mean(dim='TIME')

pl=ds_anomalies.ILD_T05.plot.contourf(
    levels=20,
    col='month',
    vmax=40,
    vmin=-40,
    #Robust=True,
    col_wrap=3,
    cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
    
    cbar_kwargs={
        "label":"MLD in m ",
        "shrink": 0.8,
        "aspect": 30,
        "fraction": 0.5,
        "anchor": (1.0,0.5),
        "location": "right",
        
    },
    subplot_kws={
        "projection": ccrs.PlateCarree()
    }
)    

for i in pl.axes.flat:
    i.coastlines()
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,
                    bottom=0.1, 
                    right=0.9, 
                    top=0.9, 
                    wspace=0.3, 
                    hspace=0.3)
    i.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
    i.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)


for i, ax in enumerate(pl.axes.flat): #to give names to the monthly plots 
    current_title = ax.get_title()
    assert current_title[:len('month = ')] == 'month = '
    month_ind = int(current_title[len('month = '):]) - 1
    ax.set_title(months[month_ind])
```

[image: plots]